# Language(s) capable of creating an easy-access shortcut UI?

Tags: windows, user-interface

Couldn't tell if this was to be in Superuser of Stackoverflow. Here's my guess

Getting straight to the point, what are some programming languages that would be able to simplistically (not [golf-standards](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), necessarily) be able to produce a program that, when run, would provide no UI initially. Though, a UI could be enabled at the press (or more specifically hold) of a button, without the standard minimize;restore-down;close Windows interface?

I have practically just provided my intentions for the program - to be able to produce the above. I understand that as each condition is added a programming language is not necessarily eliminated from the language-pool, however I am curious as for what languages would be able to do this. C++? C#? Java? Python? etc. etc.

I am running Window 7, and am not a 'master' in any language. I have simply played around with, and learned the syntax and simple controls for a small selection of languages.

Comment: How would this program know you are pressing a key if there is no UI? Are you asking how to make global hotkeys that work no matter what program has keyboard focus?

Comment: @BryanOakley - Take AutoHotKey for an example - it reads inputs without  requiring a UI to be presented on the screen. As far as I know, AutoHotKey is a valid answer to my own question - though I would like to know which (other) languages are capable.

Comment: Any language where you can access the native Windows API: C, C++, C#, python, etc, etc, etc, etc, etc.